# why error_log generate a RuntimeException only with phpunit's --process-isolation

Tags: php, unit-testing, exception, testing, phpunit

i had a few tests which code being tested outputed some `error_log` information (since i'm testing failures as well, this is expected)

e.g.

```
<?php
Class X {
    function dosomething(){
            error_log('did it');
            return true;
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
<?php
require_once 'X.php';
class xTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase {
    public function testDo(){
            $x = new X();
            $this->assertTrue( $x->dosomething(), 'dosomething returns true');
    }
}
```

which when run on php_unit *without* `--process-isolation` gives me a nice `.` and whatever i'm testing pass.

however, when run *with* `--process-isolation` i get:

```
1) test::a with data set #1 'a'
RuntimeException: did it
```

why is that happening? i'm stuck on version 3.4.12 (can't do much about it) but didn't find anything interesting in the changelog about that.

here's a sample session:

```
xxx$ phpunit xTest.php
PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

did it
.

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb

OK (1 test, 1 assertion)

shell return code: 0
xxx$ phpunit --process-isolation xTest.php
PHPUnit 3.4.12 by Sebastian Bergmann.

E

Time: 0 seconds, Memory: 4.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) xTest::testDo
RuntimeException: did it


FAILURES!
Tests: 1, Assertions: 0, Errors: 1.

shell return code: 2
```

edit: i was searching for "phpunit runtimeexception error_log" and 5sec after submiting this it's already the top search result :( there's nothing about it out there.

but i came here to edit and say this:
adding `$this->setExpectedException('RuntimeException');` does absolutely nothing to catch this. same outcome happens.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is there is a difference between the [`error_log`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-log) configuration in the outer and inner process. By default when running `error_log()` from the CLI it will be written to `stderr` and cause a test failure. What you need to do is work out why there is a difference. I would guess that you have some code that runs in the outer process that changes this configuration that is not getting run on the inner.

Comment: i assumed only return code would fail a test. So i have to steer clear of stderr output as well? that sucks for testing my code with the debug flags tuned on... how do i even overload/mock error_log? will probably have to add an abstraction there to another class just to please testing.

Comment: Adding test after the fact can be a real pain. Keep in mind that PHPUnit is intended to be used with Test Driven Development.

Comment: in this case even if it was done TDD from zero. i'd never be able to test a class that has a error_log side effect.

Comment: There are different levels of test - unit, integration, system, etc. We are talking about unit tests here. That means the class under test world need to be isolated. In production, you would most likely inject an object that would call `error_log()`. That means in the test case you would create a mock test object. When a project is create from the start using TDD, it will be structured very differently because of these needs. Adding unit test after the fact can be very hard because of the struct of the existing code. Sometime starting with integrating or system test can be easier.